# Can I use a boolean AND condition in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, boolean-operations

Say, if I have a DN string, something like this:

```
OU=Karen,OU=Office,OU=admin,DC=corp,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM
```

How to make a regular expression to pick only DNs that have both `OU=Karen` and `OU=admin`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the regex lookahead solution, matching the whole string if it contains required parts in any order just for the reference. If you do not store the pattern in some sort of configurable variable, I'd stick with nhahtdh's solution, though.

```
/^(?=.*OU=Karen)(?=.*OU=admin).*$/

^        - line start
(?=      - start zero-width positive lookahead
.*       - anything or nothing
OU=Karen - literal
)        - end zero-width positive lookahead
         - place as many positive or negative look-aheads as required
.*       - the whole line
$        - line end
```

Answer (score 6):

You realise you don't have to do *everything* with a single regex, or even *one* regex.

Regular expressions are very good for catching classes of input but, if you have two totally fixed strings, you can just use a `contains()`-type method for both of them and then `and` the results.

Alternatively, if you need to use regexes, you can do *that* twice (once per string) and `and` the results together.

If you need to do it with a *single* regex, you could try something like:

```
,OU=Karen,.*,OU=admin,|,OU=admin,.*,OU=Karen,
```

but you'll then have to also worry about when those stanzas appear at the start or end of the line, and all sorts of other edge cases (one or both at start or end, both next to each other, names like `Karen7` or `administrator-lesser`, and so on).

Having to allow for *all* possibilities will probably end up with something monstrous like:

```
^OU=Karen(,[^,]*)*,OU=admin,|
^OU=Karen(,[^,]*)*,OU=admin$|
,OU=Karen(,[^,]*)*,OU=admin,|
,OU=Karen(,[^,]*)*,OU=admin$|
^OU=admin(,[^,]*)*,OU=Karen,|
^OU=admin(,[^,]*)*,OU=Karen$|
,OU=admin(,[^,]*)*,OU=Karen,|
,OU=admin(,[^,]*)*,OU=Karen$
```

although, with an advanced enouge regex engine, this may be reducible to something smaller (although it would be unlikely to be any faster, simply because of all the forward-looking/back-tracking).

One way that *could* be improved without a complex regex is to massage your string slightly before-hand so that boundary checks aren't needed:

```
newString = "," + origString.replace (",", ",,") + ","
```

so that it starts and ends with a comma and all commas within it are duplicated:

```
,OU=Karen,,OU=Office,,OU=admin,,DC=corp,,DC=Fabrikam,,DC=COM,
```

Then you need only check for the much simpler:

```
,OU=Karen,.*,OU=admin,|,OU=admin,.*,OU=Karen,
```

and this removes all the potential problems mentioned:

- either at start of string.
- either at end of string.
- both abutting each other.
- extended names like `Karen2` being matched accidentally.

---

Probably the *best* way to do this (if your language allows) is to simply split the string on commas and examine them, something like:

```
str = "OU=Karen,OU=Office,OU=admin,DC=corp,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM"
elems[] = str.splitOn(",")

gotKaren = false
gotAdmin = false
for each elem in elems:
    if elem = "OU=Karen": gotKaren = true
    if elem = "OU=admin": gotAdmin = true

if gotKaren and gotAdmin:
    weaveYourMagicHere()
```

This both ignores the order in which they may appear and bypasses any regex "gymnastics" that may be required to detect the edge cases.

It also has the advantage of probably being more readable than the equivalent regex :-)

Comment: Again, as I said above, thanks for the explanation but this has to be a regexp only.

Comment: @ahmd0, then you can look into the regex I gave, accounting for all the possibilities I warned against. Or, provided your regex engine is advanced enough, Eugene's solution is probably the best.

Comment: +1. Forgot about splitting and check (I only consider this for repeated check in my post). Not sure, but the performance may be better this way.

Comment: @ahmd0, I've also added another possibility you should examine, that of massaging the string in advance (as a temporary string, of course) to make the RE a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use a regex, you can use

```
/OU=Karen.*?OU=admin|OU=admin.*?OU=Karen/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `contains()`, or `indexOf()` as many times as the number of conditions to check the exact string. No need for regex.

Extensible regex (as in it can support more conditions) may be possible with look ahead, but I doubt it will perform any better.

If you want to perform this type of action multiple times on the **same** string, and there are many tokens on the string, then you may consider parsing the string and store in some data structure.

Comment: Sometimes the best answer to the question "How do I X?" is "Don't do X, do Y instead." REs are a fantastic tool but so are chainsaws - I still wouldn't use them to bang in a nail :-)

Comment: I can't use any programming languages. It must be the regexp. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you're using `vi`: it has an `\&` operator

```
/(OU=Karen.*OU=admin|ou=admin.*OU=Karen)/
```

This might be close enough, though, or similar.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like (OU\=Karen

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This may well answer the question - but a bit of explanation is always a good idea. There are heaps of newbies on S/O that may learn a thing or two from you, and what may be obvious to you, won't be to them.