# How to hide certain rows via Regex with JQuery Datatable

Tags: regex, datatables

## Background

I have a datatables table of many rows of data; and a pair of custom buttons as per the Datatables documentation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   /* t is the datatable */
   var t = $('#dtabl').DataTable({
       ....
       ....
       buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Hide Horse Academys',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    t.columns(1).search('some regex', true, true).draw();
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Show Horse Academys',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    t.columns(1).search('', true, false).draw();
                }
            }
     ]
    });
});
```

These buttons should hide and show **rows** on the datatables where a certain column does or does not contain a certain text.

The text I am trying to hide was originally all rows where the column contained the word "academy";

thus:

```
    {
       text: 'Hide Horse Academys',
       action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          t.columns(1).search('^(?:(?!academy).)*', true, true).draw();
       }
    },
```

From this the Datatables search scans the column `(1)` for the text as per the [search documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()).

This uses a negative lookahead group to return finds which do not contain the value "academy".

**This works.**

## The problem

I now have be asked to develop this to only hide academy's of a certain type, so jump academys should remain in view. I figure I could do this by having a parrallel search in place to:

*Only hide rows where the word "academy" appears and the word "jump" does not appear in the text.*

But this is proving hard to do, it seems to work on Regex101.com but I can't make it work in the  Javascript on the website;

What I need  is:

- One line regex returns true if:

  - text does not contain 'academy' **OR**
  - text does contain 'academy' and does **NOT** also contain 'jump'

The code I have is:

```
 t.columns(1).search('^(?:(?!.*academy.*).(?=.*jump.*))', true, true).draw();
```

*Text that doesn't contain `academy` and does contain `jump`*

The problem with this is it is showing **only** text that contains jump

Furter development comes to this  - below -  which kind of works but sometimes misses matches;

```
 t.columns(1).search('^(?:(?!.*academy.*)(?=.*jump.*|.*)).*', true, true).draw();
```

I have read various documentation on Javascript Regex (I am more familiar with PCRE) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10827606/3536236) but I can't see how I can fit what I need into the `datatables.search()` aspect.

## Intended outcomes:

`Academy of saddles` - Hide *(contains academy does not contain jump)*
`Academy of jumps` - Show *(contains academy but also jump)*
`Show jumping academy` - Show *(contains academy but also jump)*
`Horse shoe surprise` - Show *(does not contain academy)*
`Trailer Academy` - Hide *(contains academy does not contain jump)*
`Jumpkick Academy` - Show *(contains academy but also jump)*

## Questions:

- How can I create the desired ECMA Regex?

Comment: "One line regex returns true if:
text does not contain 'academy' OR
text does contain 'academy' and does NOT also contain 'jump'" - `/^(?:(?!.*academy)|(?!.*jump).*academy)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have just been playing on Regex and I think got a very similar output to your suggestion: `^(?:(?!.*academy.*)|((?=.*jump.*)(?=.*academy.*))).*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew does your Regex matter re the second part if `jump` comes *after* `academy`?

Comment: @Martins solution is better if `jump` can come after `academy` - otherwise they works the same.

Comment: @PoulBak I have no control of the data that is being tested here so the text could appear in either order. I have a lot of `.*` in my Regex which feels superfluous but seems to help (?)

Comment: BTW: You don't need `.*`  after the search words.

Comment: I don't understand how this question "lacks focus"? Several (2) other users have given relevant and helpful information on this question which tends to suggest the question is correctly understood by readers. How could I improve the focus of this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With some digging around and exploration on a Regex tester tool I came up with a working solution:

```
^(?: (?!.*academy) | ( (?=.*jump)(?=.*academy) ) )
```

Explanation:

```
^       = start of string
(?:     = start of non-capture group
(?!     = start of negative lookahead capture group ("not contains")
.       = any character
*       = zero or more times (greedy)
academy = the literal word academy
)       = close negative capture group
|       = OR | alternative seperator
(       = second capture group 
(?=     = open positive capture group, must contain
.*      = any character, zero or more times 
jump    = the literal word jump
)       = close positive capture group
(?=     = open positive capture group 
.*      = you know this by now ;)
academy = the literal word academy
))      = close positive capture group, close alternative capture group
)       = close entire non-capture group.
```

*(Thanks to PoulBak in comments for confirming my thoughts there was too much `.*` in my original version of this)*

So the above will return true on any string that:

> Does not contain "academy"
> **OR** does contain "academy" AND "jump"

So final Datatables JS code would look like this:

```
 t.columns(1).search('^(?:(?!.*academy)|((?=.*jump)(?=.*academy)))', true, true).draw();
```